# RN - ResizeMode doesn't work on IOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to maintain image aspect ratio.
When I have specific width and resizeMode it works on Android, but not on IOS. 
Any thoughts?

image: {
    width: 150,
    resizeMode: 'center'
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resizeMode is a prop not a style. So please try this.

```
<Image
  style={{width: 150}}
  resizeMode = 'center'
/>
```

please follow this [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#resizemode) for more details.

Comment: did you try any other modes like cover, contain etc.

Comment: From what I discovered there is a bug on iOS with resize mode center. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28670

Answer (score 0):

If `resizeMode` does not work on iPhone, try using some styles like

```
width: 24,
height: 24,
resizeMode: "contain",
alignSelf: "center",
marginLeft: 12,
marginRight: 4
```